# Converting circular structure to JSON Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

[image]

The above is the returned object from firebase and I do this:

```
JSON.stringify(data) // where data is the returned object
```

Then I get the error: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

How to properly handle an object response like that from firebase?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903504/how-to-solve-uncaught-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) paints a picture of what is happening, however, in the case of firebase, how to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the `val()` method...

```
JSON.stringify(data.val())
```

Comment: You know what, I'm really far away from my Firebase code at the moment, but I think this will do the trick. Will let you know how it goes! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle the error "TypeError: Converting circular struct to JSON" when getting data from Firebase is to enumerate the key/value pairs explicitly and examine them:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
   let value = data[key];
   console.log(key + " : " + value);
});
```

The data you have is almost certainly not the data you think you have.