# How to remove circular structure in a table?

Tags: r, algorithm, igraph

I have a hierarchical data as below. But it has circular structure. I want to delete the rows that cause the circular structure.

| orderNo | from | to | group1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 0 |
| 2 | B | C | 0 |
| 3 | C | A | 0 |
| 4 | A | D | 0 |
| 1 | X | Y | 1 |
| 2 | Y | W | 1 |
| 3 | W | X | 1 |

Data is something like that. I want to remove 3th and 7th rows from dataset.

There is a problem similar to the one in the answer in the [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903504/how-to-solve-uncaught-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

How can i do this **in R?** Can anyone help me?

Comment: Pick any node, use DFS to find all nodes that are connected to it, and drop any edge that leads to an already visited node. Plenty documentation/algorithms out there to achieve something similar

Comment: there is a question here about finding cycles in igraph which might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091438/r-igraph-find-all-cycles if you convert your data to an igraph object you could use the solution there

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is using `mst`, say, ***"minimum spanning tree"***, to prune the network into a tree

```
library(igraph)
df %>%
    group_by(group1) %>%
    group_map(~ {
        graph_from_data_frame(relocate(.x, c(orderNo, group1), .after = to)) %>%
            mst() %>%
            as_data_frame()
    }, .keep = TRUE) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    select(names(df))
```

which gives

```
  orderNo from to group1
1       1    A  B      0
2       3    C  A      0
3       4    A  D      0
4       1    X  Y      1
5       3    W  X      1
```

## data

```
df <- read.table(
    text = "orderNo from    to  group1
1   A   B   0
2   B   C   0
3   C   A   0
4   A   D   0
1   X   Y   1
2   Y   W   1
3   W   X   1",
    header = TRUE,
    check.names = FALSE
)
```